# change script from php to js

Tags: javascript, php, json

i'm new on javascript, but I need to add some javascript on my web
I really do not understand about js. please tell me how to make this script on js

```
$provinces = $this->rajaongkir->province();
$provincelist = json_decode($provinces, true);
```

thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

i still didnt understand your question are you gonna make a json object into javascript object if it is so then maybe this script will help assuming that you have php object name `$provincelist` then to change it just pass it into script like this:

```
<code>
<script language="text/javascript">
var jsObject = <?php json_encode($provincelist); ?>
</script>
</code>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you exactly asking for, but try this code, this may help you

Javascript code:

```
provinces = this.rajaongkir.province;
provincelist = JSON.parse(provinces);
```